# Convert datetime string from specific time zone to another specific timezone

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a HIVE table of orders from different locations. This table contains a string column containing the date and time of each order. There is also another column with the corresponding timezone.For some reason, however, the value in the timezone column is not the local one. Then for each date, I have the corresponding timezone and a target timezone to convert. Like this:

```sql
with orders as (
    select 1 as order_id, '2022-07-20 15:04:12' as create_time, 'UTC' as create_tz, 'BRT' as target_tz
    union all
    select 2 as order_id, '2022-07-20 17:34:14' as create_time, 'CET' as create_tz, 'PST' as target_tz
) select * from orders;
```

| order_id | create_time | create_tz | target_tz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-20 15:04:12 | UTC | BRT |
| 2 | 2022-07-20 17:34:14 | CET | PST |

I need to print a string column with the local date and time (and also make the timezone explicit). Like this:

| order_id | local_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-20 12:04:12 BRT |
| 2 | 2022-07-20 08:34:14 PST |

My approach was to convert everything to UTC and then print it using the function `from_unixtime`, however it seems that this function always print the result in the client's time (in my case CST). I didn't find a way to set a target timezone for each record.

```sql
with orders as (
    select 1 as order_id, '2022-07-20 15:04:12' as create_time, 'UTC' as create_tz, 'BRT' as target_tz
    union all
    select 2 as order_id, '2022-07-20 17:34:14' as create_time, 'CET' as create_tz, 'PST' as target_tz
) select
    order_id,
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(create_time, ' ', create_tz), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z'),  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')
from orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not an elegant workaround, but it seems to work:

```sql
with orders as (
    select 1 as order_id, '2022-07-20 15:04:12' as create_time, 'UTC' as create_tz, 'BRT' as target_tz
    union all
    select 2 as order_id, '2022-07-20 17:34:14' as create_time, 'CET' as create_tz, 'PST' as target_tz
) select
    order_id,
    concat(from_unixtime(
        unix_timestamp(create_time)
        + unix_timestamp(concat('1970-01-01 00:00:00', ' ', create_tz), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')
        - unix_timestamp(concat('1970-01-01 00:00:00', ' ', target_tz), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')
    ), ' ', target_tz)
from orders;
```